# STM8 Assembly startup code: Access Core registers to initialize stack pointer

Tags: startup, stack-pointer, sdcc, stm8

I am currently trying to write startup code in assembly for an STM8 without any vendor libraries. More specifically, I am using an STM8S103f3p6. I am still inexperienced in assembly and with startup code, but I am confident to know what has to be done at the start of a µC. But apparently I don't know, HOW it is done.
For assembly, I am currently using the [STM8-AS](https://sourceforge.net/projects/stm8-binutils-gdb/files/) which is based on GNU AS. At the very start of my reset_handler, I want to set the stack pointer to the end of RAM 0x0003FF like shown in the [datasheet (direct download)](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm8s103f2.pdf). But the reference manual states that the stack pointer (SPH and SPL) can not be accessed by memory access instructions. But setting the SP in debug mode can't be correct, can it? I am unsure what to make of that
[image]

Comment: Looks like the way you'd load a value into SP on this processor is `LDW X,#immediate` followed by `LDW SP,X`.  (Loading a value directly into SP is something that would be done exactly once in a normal program, so no point in wasting an opcode on that.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [data sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm8s103f2.pdf) table 9, the SP holds 0x03FF on reset. So you don't need to set it explicitly in this case. The [programming manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/programming_manual/pm0044-stm8-cpu-programming-manual-stmicroelectronics.pdf) says the same in chapter 3.2:

> After an MCU reset the Stack Pointer is set to its upper limit value.

However, if you want to load a value into the SP, you can use only one of these instructions according to the programming manual (chapter 7.4 on `LDW`):

- `LDW SP, X`
- `LDW SP, Y`

The registers `X` and `Y` can be loaded before with immediate values, for example `LDW Y, #$03FF`.

The complete sequence with `Y` is:

```
        LDW Y, #$03FF
        LDW SP, Y
```